# Is there an alternative to preprocessorScript for Chrome DevTools extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to create a custom profiler for Javascript as a Chrome DevTools Extension. To do so, I'd have to instrument all Javascript code of a website (parse to AST, inject hooks, generate new source). This should've been easily possible using `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload()` and its parameter `preprocessorScript` described here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow.

Unfortunately, this feature has been removed (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438626) because nobody was using it.

Do you know of any other way I could achieve the same thing with a Chrome Extension? Is there any other way I can replace an incoming Javascript source with a changed version? This question is very specific to Chrome Extensions (and maybe extensions to other browsers), I'm asking this as a last resort before going a different route (e.g. dedicated app).

Comment: TIL: Depending on the specific profiling needs, I might also use [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) to use tracing facilities of V8 directly using the [Debugging Protocol](http://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Tracing/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Chrome Debugging Protocol.

First, use `DOMDebugger.setInstrumentationBreakpoint` with `eventName: "scriptFirstStatement"` as a parameter to add a break-point to the first statement of each script.

Second, in the Debugger Domain, there is an event called `scriptParsed`. Listen to it and if called, use `Debugger.setScriptSource` to change the source.

Finally, call `Debugger.resume` each time after you edited a source file with `setScriptSource`.

Example in semi-pseudo-code:

```
// Prevent code being executed
cdp.sendCommand("DOMDebugger.setInstrumentationBreakpoint", {
  eventName: "scriptFirstStatement"
});

// Enable Debugger domain to receive its events
cdp.sendCommand("Debugger.enable");

cdp.addListener("message", (event, method, params) => {
  // Script is ready to be edited
  if (method === "Debugger.scriptParsed") {
    cdp.sendCommand("Debugger.setScriptSource", {
      scriptId: params.scriptId,
      scriptSource: `console.log("edited script ${params.url}");`
    }, (err, msg) => {
      // After editing, resume code execution.
      cdg.sendCommand("Debugger.resume");
    });        
  }
});
```

The implementation above is not ideal. It should probably listen to the breakpoint event, get to the script using the associated event data, edit the script and then resume. Listening to `scriptParsed` and then resuming the debugger are two things that shouldn't be together, it could create problems. It makes for a simpler example, though.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of this by any chance? I've been playing around with this tonight but haven't fully got it working yet.

Answer (score 0):

On HTTP you can use the [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to redirect requests for JS code to data URLs containing the processed JavaScript code.

However, this won't work for inline script tags. It also won't work on HTTPS, since the data URLs are considered unsafe. And data URLs are can't be longer than 2MB in Chrome, so you won't be able to redirect to large JS files.

If the exact order of execution of each script isn't important you could cancel the script requests and then later send a message with the script content to the page. This would make it work on HTTPS.

To address both issues you could redirect the HTML page itself to a data URL, in order to gain more control. That has a few negative consequences though:

1. Can't reload page because URL is fixed to data URL
2. Need to add or update `<base>` tag to make sure stylesheet/image URLs go to the correct URL
3. Breaks ajax requests that require cookies/authentication (not sure if this can be fixed)
4. No support for localStorage on data URLs

Not sure if this works: in order to fix #1 and #4 you could consider setting up an HTML page within your Chrome extension and then using that as the base page instead of a data URL.

Another idea that may or may not work: Use [`chrome.debugger`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Debugger/#method-setScriptSource) to modify the source code.

Comment: The chrome.webRequestAPI doesn't allow to modify any network response, for most events "It does not allow modifying or cancelling the request", see onResponseStarted for example. Or did you mean some other way?

Comment: `webRequest` can't [read](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422) nor [modify](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) responses. Only headers and only some of them.

Comment: You're both right, I misunderstood what the capabilities of webRequest are.