# how can i intercept JS code before exectution in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to create chrome extension to dev tool where i would like to intercept JS code of current web page before it is compiled or executed by browser ,
Actually i want to instrument JS code before it to run in browser.

Can anybody will help us , how it is possible ?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: In chrome dev tool extension how can i intercept scripts before they are loaded by browser.
So that i can run instrumented code instead of original

Comment: It's a very broad topic, and the question has the form "I want X, help us do the whole thing". You should show what you have researched/tried yourself already, and try to narrow the question down. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: yes, you are right, actually i do not ask for solution to my problem , just need some suggestion about in which direction i should research to achieve my goal. Thanks

Comment: There's no easy way to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429962/is-there-an-alternative-to-preprocessorscript-for-chrome-devtools-extensions/37440500#37440500
This is some of the code I'm using at the moment: https://github.com/mattzeunert/FromJS/blob/master/chrome-extension/background.js It basically tries to prevent the original code from running and then injects the instrumented code later on. I'm currently in the process of refactoring it to be more re-usable for other projects.

Comment: Many Thanks , i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ways to hook into the loading process itself, but scripts with an unknown type are not processed as scripts, this in combination with the fact that scripts with a custom type do not execute is what the following hack relies on.

Calling `window.stop` will stop the document from loading in its tracks, if we call this at the very top of the document, we can assume that the document did not load.

Then, we can make a XHR request to get the content of the document, and do a little bit of search and replace to render all scripts in the document inert by giving them a custom script type before writing this modified to the document.

```
window.stop();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', location.href);
request.onload = function(event) {
  var html = request.responseText
    .replace(/type=\"text\/javascript\"/g, '')
    .replace(/<script/g, '<script type="x-instrument/javascript"');

  document.open();
  document.write(html);
  document.close();
};

request.send(null);
```

At this point, all scripts have been rendered inert, a basic sequential loader could look something like the following:

```
setTimeout(function next(index) {
  var script = document.scripts[index];
  if (script == null) {
    return setTimeout(callback, 0);
  }

  if (script.hasAttribute('src')) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', script.getAttribute('src'));
    request.onload = function() {
      var code = instrument(request.responseText);
      eval(code);

      setTimeout(next, 0, ++index);
    };

    request.send(null);
  } else {
    var code = instrument(script.textContent);
    eval(code);

    setTimeout(next, 0, ++index);
  }
}, 0, 0);
```

With this, any page can be instrumented by inserting this script into the beginning of a document.

You can also load it as a content script in a chrome extension however, make sure that `run_at` is set to `document_start`.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "instrument",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["instrument.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "instrument.js"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

[Example](https://github.com/hasharray/thingamajig.js/tree/master)

Comment: This is a workable idea, but please note that an XHR loses some of the properties of the original request, potentially breaking some sites (e.g. Referrer).

Comment: @Xan true, an alternative approach is to let the document continue loading but write an open ended `<template>` tag instead of calling `window.stop`, thus removing the extra XHR request but still rendering an inert document which can be manipulated.

Comment: @CasperBeyer I am new to Chrome extensions , Can you please suggest me where should i place libraries to instrument the code , will it be content script or part of background ?

Comment: @CasperBeyer  if i move instrumentation logic to background then i am unable to call it from content script because message passing available between content script and background script is asynchronous.

Comment: @waqasabbas I would just build a release bundle with all dependencies etc. The only thing the extension is doing here is being an invisible man in the middle injecting it into the very beginning of the document. Just think in terms of 'how would this work as a script inserted into the head section`, making it standalone without any external deps for example is a good thing.

Comment: @CasperBeyer I need your help again, I am intercepting js with your method , I am facing problem if orignal code contains inside document ready or $(function () { alert("test");  }); Then it does not execute after instrumentation. Even if my instrumentation return orignal code. And idea to resolve that ?

Comment: @CasperBeyer with regard to the writing an open ended <template> tag
what method would you use to do this? 
if i put document.write("<template>");
in my content script, it inserts <template>#document-fragment</template> into the head tag of the page, doesnt seem to work how you suggested, i guess im doing something wrong? what would the correct way to do that  be?